# c++ polymorphism with dynamic_cast and typeid

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

Say I have a parent `class Shape` and two children class `class Square` and
`class Circle`.

At some point in my code I do something like :

```
Shape* genericshape;
if(a_time_consuming_test()){
    genericshape = new Square;
} else {
    genericshape = new Cricle;
}
```

And later I would like to create another Circle or Square but I don't want to
call `a_time_consuming_test()`. So can I use `typeid` or some equivalent to
directly create the "right" shape ? Something like :

```
if(typeid(genericshape) == typeid(Square)){
    Square newsquare;
} else {
    Circle newcircle;
}
```

I guess that there should be a solution of that kind but this doesn't seem to
be efficient because the day I have a third shape, like `Triangle`, I would
need to check for each children of `Shape`. Would something like this be
possible ?

```
Shape* newshape(&genericshape);
```

I mean, would `newshape` be a pointer on the same child class as
`genericshape`?

## EDIT

Looking at one of the answers, I should have specified that `Shape`, `Square` and `Circle` are actually template class.

Comment: I've too many solutions in my mind, but without knowing how exactly it is going to be used, I cannot say which solution would really be suitable for your case.  You can try `enum shape_type { circle, square, traingle, etc}; ` then save the type of your object in a variable of type `shape_type`, which you can later use. That is one way of doing it; other is, store  a map of type_info and factory function, then use it.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [virtual constructor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor).

Comment: I think you want a new object of the same type. Maybe have a virtual method `Shape *Clone()` or `Shape *newShapeOfSameKind()`in the base class which is overriden by derived classes so that it always creates an object of the proper type when called for a `Shape *` (which may point to a Square, Triangle or Circle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is a simple cloning functionality, with the slight twist that it will not clone the data, only the type. So you could add something like this to `Shape`:

```
struct Shape
{
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Shape> createEmptyObject() const = 0;

  // The rest as before
}:


struct Circle
{
  std::unique_ptr<Shape> createEmptyObject() const override
  { return std::make_unique<Circle>(/*ctor args here*/); }

  // The rest as before
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
Shape* genericshape;
if(a_time_consuming_test()){
    genericshape = new Square;
} else {
    genericshape = new Cricle;
}
// ...
auto anotherShape = genericshape->createEmptyObject();
```

Note: if you don't have access to C++14, you will have to replace `make_unique` with a manually constructed `unique_ptr`:

```
return std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Circle(/*ctor args here*/));
```

Comment: This look nice, but would it be possible to use that solution with template class?

Comment: @PinkFloyd Why not? It depends on *how* the template's parameters are used, of course. If you want a more accurate answer, provide a more accurate description in the question.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, template and virtual are not really good friend... it is not possible to have a template virtual method ? or am I wrong ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd You cannot have a virtual member function template, but a class template can have virtual member functions just fine.

Comment: @PinkFloyd Added in C++11, very useful feature. You should read up on C++11, it has really improved the language.

Comment: Even if I compile my code with c++11, (gcc 4.7.2) it seems that I don't have std::make_unique. any idea to solve that ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd Whoops, that's C++14 only. I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ready to edit the following typelist, everytime you a add new shape:

```
using shapes = typelist<circle, rectangle>;
```

then I think the following solution should work (explained step-by-step):

```
shape* create(shape const * s)
{
    return create_impl(shapes(), s);
}
```

where `create_impl` and other supports are defined as:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct typelist{};

using shapes = typelist<circle, rectangle>;

template<typename T, typename ...Rest>
shape* create_impl(typelist<T, Rest...>, shape const *s)
{
     if ( typeid(T) == typeid(*s) )
        return new T();
     else
        return create_impl(typelist<Rest...>(), s);
}

template<typename T>
shape* create_impl(typelist<T>, shape const *s)
{ 
     return typeid(T) == typeid(*s)? new T() : nullptr;

}
```

Later if you add a new shape,say `triangle`, then just add it to the typelist:

```
using shapes = typelist<circle, rectangle, triangle>;
```

then everything should work again. No other code change.

And of course, you should use smart pointer instead of raw pointer, but I guess that is a small modification in the above code. The basic idea will remain same.